# React render an object into a list

Tags: reactjs

I am creating a list of items by using the `map` function:

```
render() {

    var accounts = this.props.accounts.map((account, index) =>
        <li className="list-group-item" key={index}>{account[0]}<br />
            <button type="button" >Go to Login</button>
            <button type="button" >Log out</button>
        </li>
    );

    return (

        {accounts && (
            <ul className="accounts-list list-group">{accounts}</ul>
        )}

    )

}
```

This works fine because accounts is an Array.

**I need to do the same thing with an Object:**

```
{
  "offer": [
    "id",
    "price-input"
  ],
  "offer_message": [
    "id",
    "msg-textarea"
  ]
}
```

**Code:**

```
forms = Object.entries(this.props.forms).forEach(([key, value]) =>

    <div className="form-group">
        {value}
    </div>

)

return (

    {forms}

)
```

This yields no result. In fact, `forms` is undefined. How do I go about rendering a list from an object?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `forEach` which returns `undefined`. You want to use `map` instead.

Also make sure that you wrap `{forms}` in an element and that you give each child in the array a `key` prop.

**Example**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const forms = Object.entries(this.props.forms).map(([key, values]) =>
      <div className="form-group" key={key}>
        {values.join(", ")}
      </div>
    );

    return <div>{forms}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App
    forms={{
      offer: ["id", "price-input"],
      offer_message: ["id", "msg-textarea"]
    }}
  />,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Multiline code should be wrapped in a parentheses. Otherwise, it will return `undefined` as you noticed:

```
=>
(
 <div className="form-group">
   {value}
  </div>
)
```